# Too many actions/filters!

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

New to wordpress here. The concept of actions/filters in and of itself is not too difficult to grasp. What I am overwhelmed by is the HUGE amount of actions and filters available. When I am looking at tutorials/guides, they say "simply add this function to the wp_head action or after_setup_theme". Without these tutorials, how on earth would i know to hook that function to that action?

As a beginner, how the heck would i know what is the appropriate action to hook on to? Any advice on how to navigate this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Mike's answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/339/2487) more specifically the plugin he posted there can be used to create a list of all action hooks and filters that were called to generate that page in order of execution.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to learn [the most important filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) is to read the source code. Whenever you want to change the output of a function **read its source**. Then you’ll either find the hook in this function or in another function called by the first. In some cases there is no hook and you have [to hack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38900/73) … but that’s the next level.

There are some [tools to inspect hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56224/73), and you will write your own probably sooner or later. But nothing beats reading the source.

Comment: And as a quick tip to others coming across this... here's what I do: I keep a mirror of the Wordpress git repository on my machine, and when I want to find a hook... fire up a command prompt and `git grep` till I get what I want