# Is there any debug toolbar that shows whick hooks are called for the current page in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, hooks, debug

In Django there is a debug toolbar that shows which template files and hooks are called while rendering a page.

Is there any plugin that shows which hooks are called for the current page in Wordpress?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There sure is, I talk about some of those options in this Q&A here: [Is there a flowchart for wordpress loading sequence?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence/71411#71411)

Here is a very brief summary of what was said,

> Want to see what actions get fired during a request? Take a look at
>   this [plugin](https://gist.github.com/1979171) by [Toscho](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/219)
>
> Want to see what's hooked and where with what priority? Take a look at
>   this [plugin](http://www.rarst.net/script/debug-wordpress-hooks/) by [Rarst](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/367)
>
> And there's also this [plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info) by [Kaiser](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/7914) (*Displays info about the current admin screen and its globals, contextual hooks*)

There is also this plugin [Debug Bar Action Hooks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar-action-hooks/) (requires [Debugbar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/)).

By no means is this list exclusive...

Answer (score 3):

There is also this plug-in: https://github.com/stephenh1988/sh-hook-debug

Built by myself and based on my answer to this question: [How can I find out what functions are assigned to actions?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56223/how-can-i-find-out-what-functions-are-assigned-to-actions/56245#56245))

It adds a search to the admin bar, and allows you to search through all hooks that were used. Clicking that hook, you are presented with a list of functions hooked onto it. If it was called more than once, it has the hooked functions for each instance (as this may vary between calls).

[image: sh-hook-debug screenshot]